# How can I write query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of mongodb like this :

```
[{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc4"")",
   "name":"CS 101",
   "students":[
      {
         "name":"raj",
         "year":2016
      },
      {
         "name":"rahul",
         "year":2017
      },
      {
         "name":"anil",
         "year":2018
      }
   ]
},
{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fs4"")",
   "name":"CS 102",
   "students":[
      {
         "name":"mukesh",
         "year":2016
      },
      {
         "name":"mohan",
         "year":2017
      },
      {
         "name":"mangal",
         "year":2018
      }
   ]
}
]
```

I've been looking for similar questions like this one: Mongo db - Querying nested array and objects but in that question they're looking for a specific element inside the "messages" object (in my case) for example. Same as in this other question: Query for a field in an object in an array with Mongo? where they're using $mapan d I don't think it fits my needs.

The documents to find have this structure:

```
[{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fc4"")",
   "name":"CS 101",
   "students":[
    "raj","rahul","anil"
   ]
},
{
   "_id":"ObjectId(""51780fb5c9c41825e3e21fs4"")",
   "name":"CS 102",
   "students":[
     "mukesh","mohan","mangal"
   ]
}
]
```

how to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried, @krishna, and what were the results? MongoDB has some great online docs, I think https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/ has the exact example you are looking for.

Comment: @krishna please modify question that what you want, this question is bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question and datasets, you are trying to return `students` with an array of student's name (string) instead of the array of student object.

Use `$project` to display `students` as `students.name` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": "$name",
      "students": "$students.name"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Solution 1 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RuGgZ-SDT_x)

OR

Use `$set` to replace the `students` field with `students.name` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "students": "$students.name"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Solution 2 on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7gfBYH-3CLp)